# Jenkins2.0 pipeline script reject date arithmetic

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code in groovy Jenkinsfile:

```
def current = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').parse(currenttime.trim())
println current
def end_date = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').parse(scheduled_end_date.trim())
println end_date
schedule_grace_period_validity = current - end_date > 5 ? false : true
```

the output for this is :

```
Tue Feb 27 13:20:54 EST 2018
[Pipeline] echo
Mon Dec 18 18:00:00 EST 2017
[Pipeline] echo
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DateGroovyMethods minus java.util.Date java.util.Date
```

This works just fine in my local box but in sandbox mode in Jenkins, this fails and I can't turn off the sandbox mode in Jenkins.

IS there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to go to `/scriptApproval/` page in your Jenkins instance and approve the signature. When you get this exception after running your script you will see something like this in the script approval page:

[image]

Just click <kbd>Approve</kbd> and run your script again.

Alternatively you could try calculating difference between two dates in days as:

```
int diff = BigDecimal.valueOf((current.time - end_date.time) / 86400000).setScale(0, java.math.RoundingMode.UP).intValue()
```

but in this case you may also run into `RejectedAccessException`. I tried to run it in Groovy sandbox in my local Jenkins instance and I got this:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.util.Date getTime
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor$6.reject(SandboxInterceptor.java:261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:381)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:284)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checke
```

Comment: I have no exception to approve in my /scriptApproval/ page for this error.

Comment: I was catching the exception so Jenkins would fail with this error but not display the approval in /scriptApproval/. You have to fail with explicit error and not handle it for jenkins to display that approval for you. Thanks!